# What is a best way of defining a very large array (lookup table)?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to define a large array (lookup table) in a code.
It contains 256 elements and takes nearly 1 computer screen.

There are two functions that are using this array.
I want to define this array under functions, so I could access them very quickly during development.

But if I try to do it inside one file, compiler will give "Undeclared identifier" errors around functions - because they use array.

So, I must put the functions and the array to separate files.

Here is the structure of my program:

```
main.cpp:

#include "lookup.h"

...uses two functions...
```

-

```
lookup.h:

#ifndef SubMaster_lookup_h
#define SubMaster_lookup_h

void func1(void);
void func2(void);

char LookupTable[][3]={ "00", "01", "02" "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09",
"0a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "0e", "0f", "00", "01", "02" "03", "04", "05", "06", "07",
"08", "09", "0a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "0e", "0f", "10", "11", "12", "13", and so on...}
```

-

```
lookup.cpp:

#include "lookup.h"

void func1() {
   ...body of func1...
}

void func2() {
   ...body of func2...
}
```

The following structure gives me "ld: duplicate symbol _LookupTable" during build.
Is there any way to change the structure, so it will not give errors?

Comment: You're storing numbers as strings...?

Comment: Lookup Table is the fastest way of converting hex values to char.

Comment: @Jake: Are you sure? On modern CPUs such a large table would consume a large amount of cache, which is expensive. Moreover, such a table gets stored in your binary, which makes startup time slower, as it has to be read from disk. Try this against the normal method of a couple of IFs and only continue if you can see a measureable difference in favor of the lookup table.

Comment: @BillyONeal I will have a lot of data to process, and a lot of operations with lookup table. I agree that startup time will be slower, but my main interest is processing performance.

Comment: @BillyONeal Thank you for your answer, after I will finish my app, I will try both ways and benchmark them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two ways:

- ***Declare* the array in the header and *define* it in a cpp file**
- Make it static. But this is pretty nasty (each translation unit will get its own copy)

Try this:

```
lookup.h
extern char LookupTable[][3];

lookup.cpp
#include "lookup.h"

char LookupTable[][3] = ...
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/714501) is good.

Answer (score 3):

You can have `extern char const lookupTable[][3];` in the header, and the actual implementation in a source file:

```
#include "header.h"

char const lookupTable[][3] = { /* ... */ }
```

Alternatively, declare the array as `static char const lookupTable[][3] = /*...*/` in the header, but then you get repeated copies in each TU (each with static (i.e. internal) linkage).

Comment: Thank you! cnicutar was first and I gave him "best answer", so I thumb up your answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Put it into a `.cpp` and write an `extern` declaration for it into the `.h`. Or, mark it as `static` (but that will result in an additional copy of that lookup table for each `.cpp` that includes the `.h`, so you should probably avoid it).

Comment: Thank you! cnicutar was first and I gave him "best answer", so I thumb up your answer instead.